# ¿Cómo interpretar este diagrama de flujo a código?

Tags: c++, c, diagrama-de-flujo

En teoría es algo relacionado al ordenamiento burbuja en *C++*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta "*¿Cómo interpretar es diagrama de flujo?*" Lo lees y lo interpretas.

Answer (score 2):

**DESCRIPCIÓN DEL ALGORITMO**
Nombre: Algoritmo de Ordenamiento de burbuja. (*Bubble sort* en inglés)
Descripción: Funciona revisando cada elemento de la lista que va a ser ordenada con el siguiente, intercambiándolos de posición si están en el orden equivocado.

**FLUJO**

1. Establecer valor de n.
2. Repetir la siguiente instrucción n veces:
   2.1 Ingresar el valor del índice i de un arreglo.
3. Repetir la siguiente instrucción n veces, se utiliza i como índice:
   3.1 Repetir la siguiente instrucción n veces, se utiliza j como índice. 
   3.1.1 Si el elemento de tu arreglo con índice j es mayor el elemento siguiente (j+1) entonces: Intercambia los elementos de posición.
4. Repetir la siguiente instrucción n veces, se utiliza i como índice:
   4.1    Imprimir el valor del elemento que ocupa el índice i dentro del arreglo.

*NOTAS:*

- Las variables contadores e índices de los arreglos comienzan en 1.
- Después de cada repetición de un bloque de instrucciones el valor del contador incrementa en 1.

**RESUMEN**

- En los pasos del 1 al 2 se establece el valor de n, que servirá para llenar un arreglo de dicha longitud.
- En el paso 3 se recorre el arreglo nxn (n^2) veces, ya que hay un ciclo de 1...n anidado a otro. Este se encarga de comparar cada elemento del arreglo con su elemento contiguo, para, en caso de ser mayor el elemento de la izquierda intercambie posición con el de la derecha. Teniendo como resultado final el arreglo ordenado en orden ascendente.
- En el paso 4 se imprimen los valores del arreglo ya ordenado.

**DEMOSTRACIÓN**

[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bubble-sort.gif]

**IMPLEMENTACIÓN EN C++**
https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/C-Plus-Plus/blob/master/sorting/bubble_sort.cpp